# Getting "No function matches the given name and argument types" when converting points to Polygons / Voronoi Diagram

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, sql, geometry

I have these points

[image: Points]

stored in my database. Now I am trying to use to create a Voronoi diagram with ST_VoronoiPolygons(). I have tried doing:

```
SELECT 
     (ST_DUMP(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geog)))).geom 
 FROM sources;
```

But this returns an error:

```
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 42
```

The goal is to turn the points into polygons. I have also tried

```
 WITH sources(geog) AS 
 (SELECT 
      ST_MakePoint(random(), random()) 
   FROM generate_series(1, 1342))
 SELECT 
     (ST_DUMP(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom 
 FROM points;
```

But this just returned a square Voronoi and not a Voronoi diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ST_VoronoiPolygons only works on geometry data types not geography data types.

`CREATE TABLE voronoi_dump AS SELECT (st_dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(st_collect(geog::geometry)))).geom FROM sources;`

Comment: Hello, @heikkiVesanto is there a way to interpolate instead of voronoi using postgis?

Comment: Best to ask as a new question.

Comment: SELECT (source_id,st_dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(st_collect(geog::geometry)))).geom FROM sources; How can I also copy the source_id?

Comment: You need to do a spatial join back onto the points.